# DELPHI : HardDisk unequal Manufacture Serial number Source Code Modifing

Tags: delphi, unicode, ansi, hard-drive

I have a code to get HDD manufacture Serial number, and it always works well for me...
But after version up from Delphi 7 to Delphi 2010, this code doesn't work anymore.
Of course, I think that the reason related difference between UNICODE and ANSI supporting by DELPHI version.
But now, converting for DELPHI 2010 is hard to me...
If you have a such code sample that works on DELPHI unicode supporting version,
or could modify my code to use for DELPHI unicode version easily, Please give me help..
Thanks to read my post...
Below is my original code that works well on DELPHI 7.

```
unit HDD_Serial;

interface

uses Windows, SysUtils;

function GetHddSerial: String;

implementation

function GetIdeDiskSerialNumber: String;
type
  TSrbIoControl = packed record
    HeaderLength: ULONG;
    Signature: Array [0 .. 7] of Char;
    Timeout: ULONG;
    ControlCode: ULONG;
    ReturnCode: ULONG;
    Length: ULONG;
  end;

  SRB_IO_CONTROL = TSrbIoControl;
  PSrbIoControl = ^TSrbIoControl;

  TIDERegs = packed record
    bFeaturesReg: Byte; // Used for specifying SMART "commands".
    bSectorCountReg: Byte; // IDE sector count register
    bSectorNumberReg: Byte; // IDE sector number register
    bCylLowReg: Byte; // IDE low order cylinder value
    bCylHighReg: Byte; // IDE high order cylinder value
    bDriveHeadReg: Byte; // IDE drive/head register
    bCommandReg: Byte; // Actual IDE command.
    bReserved: Byte; // reserved for future use. Must be zero.
  end;

  IDEREGS = TIDERegs;
  PIDERegs = ^TIDERegs;

  TSendCmdInParams = packed record
    cBufferSize: DWORD; // Buffer size in bytes
    irDriveRegs: TIDERegs; // Structure with drive register values.
    bDriveNumber: Byte; // Physical drive number to send command to (0,1,2,3).
    bReserved: Array [0 .. 2] of Byte; // Reserved for future expansion.
    dwReserved: Array [0 .. 3] of DWORD; // For future use.
    bBuffer: Array [0 .. 0] of Byte; // Input buffer.
  end;

  SENDCMDINPARAMS = TSendCmdInParams;
  PSendCmdInParams = ^TSendCmdInParams;

  TIdSector = packed record
    wGenConfig: Word;
    wNumCyls: Word;
    wReserved: Word;
    wNumHeads: Word;
    wBytesPerTrack: Word;
    wBytesPerSector: Word;
    wSectorsPerTrack: Word;
    wVendorUnique: Array [0 .. 2] of Word;
    sSerialNumber: Array [0 .. 19] of Char;
    wBufferType: Word;
    wBufferSize: Word;
    wECCSize: Word;
    sFirmwareRev: Array [0 .. 7] of Char;
    sModelNumber: Array [0 .. 39] of Char;
    wMoreVendorUnique: Word;
    wDoubleWordIO: Word;
    wCapabilities: Word;
    wReserved1: Word;
    wPIOTiming: Word;
    wDMATiming: Word;
    wBS: Word;
    wNumCurrentCyls: Word;
    wNumCurrentHeads: Word;
    wNumCurrentSectorsPerTrack: Word;
    ulCurrentSectorCapacity: ULONG;
    wMultSectorStuff: Word;
    ulTotalAddressableSectors: ULONG;
    wSingleWordDMA: Word;
    wMultiWordDMA: Word;
    bReserved: Array [0 .. 127] of Byte;
  end;

  PIdSector = ^TIdSector;
const
  IDE_ID_FUNCTION = $EC;
  IDENTIFY_BUFFER_SIZE = 512;
  DFP_RECEIVE_DRIVE_DATA = $0007C088;
  IOCTL_SCSI_MINIPORT = $0004D008;
  IOCTL_SCSI_MINIPORT_IDENTIFY = $001B0501;
  DataSize = sizeof(TSendCmdInParams) - 1 + IDENTIFY_BUFFER_SIZE;
  BufferSize = sizeof(SRB_IO_CONTROL) + DataSize;
  W9xBufferSize = IDENTIFY_BUFFER_SIZE + 16;
var
  hDevice: THandle;
  cbBytesReturned: DWORD;
  pInData: PSendCmdInParams;
  pOutData: Pointer; // PSendCmdInParams;
  Buffer: Array [0 .. BufferSize - 1] of Byte;
  srbControl: TSrbIoControl absolute Buffer;

  procedure ChangeByteOrder(var Data; Size: Integer);
  var
    ptr: PChar;
    i: Integer;
    c: Char;
  begin
    ptr := @Data;
    for i := 0 to (Size shr 1) - 1 do
    begin
      c := ptr^;
      ptr^ := (ptr + 1)^;
      (ptr + 1)^ := c;
      Inc(ptr, 2);
    end;
  end;

begin
  Result := '';
  FillChar(Buffer, BufferSize, #0);
  if Win32Platform = VER_PLATFORM_WIN32_NT then
  begin // Windows NT, Windows 2000
    // Get SCSI port handle
    hDevice := CreateFile('\\.\Scsi0:', GENERIC_READ or GENERIC_WRITE,
      FILE_SHARE_READ or FILE_SHARE_WRITE, nil, OPEN_EXISTING, 0, 0);
    if hDevice = INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE then
      Exit;
    try
      srbControl.HeaderLength := sizeof(SRB_IO_CONTROL);
      System.Move('SCSIDISK', srbControl.Signature, 8);
      srbControl.Timeout := 2;
      srbControl.Length := DataSize;
      srbControl.ControlCode := IOCTL_SCSI_MINIPORT_IDENTIFY;
      pInData := PSendCmdInParams(PChar(@Buffer) + sizeof(SRB_IO_CONTROL));
      pOutData := pInData;
      with pInData^ do
      begin
        cBufferSize := IDENTIFY_BUFFER_SIZE;
        bDriveNumber := 0;
        with irDriveRegs do
        begin
          bFeaturesReg := 0;
          bSectorCountReg := 1;
          bSectorNumberReg := 1;
          bCylLowReg := 0;
          bCylHighReg := 0;
          bDriveHeadReg := $A0;
          bCommandReg := IDE_ID_FUNCTION;
        end;
      end;
      if not DeviceIoControl(hDevice, IOCTL_SCSI_MINIPORT, @Buffer, BufferSize,
        @Buffer, BufferSize, cbBytesReturned, nil) then
        Exit;
    finally
      CloseHandle(hDevice);
    end;
  end
  else
  begin // Windows 95 OSR2, Windows 98
    hDevice := CreateFile('\\.\SMARTVSD', 0, 0, nil, CREATE_NEW, 0, 0);
    if hDevice = INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE then
      Exit;
    try
      pInData := PSendCmdInParams(@Buffer);
      pOutData := PChar(@pInData^.bBuffer);
      with pInData^ do
      begin
        cBufferSize := IDENTIFY_BUFFER_SIZE;
        bDriveNumber := 0;
        with irDriveRegs do
        begin
          bFeaturesReg := 0;
          bSectorCountReg := 1;
          bSectorNumberReg := 1;
          bCylLowReg := 0;
          bCylHighReg := 0;
          bDriveHeadReg := $A0;
          bCommandReg := IDE_ID_FUNCTION;
        end;
      end;
      if not DeviceIoControl(hDevice, DFP_RECEIVE_DRIVE_DATA, pInData,
        sizeof(TSendCmdInParams) - 1, pOutData, W9xBufferSize, cbBytesReturned,
        nil) then
        Exit;
    finally
      CloseHandle(hDevice);
    end;
  end;
  with PIdSector(PChar(pOutData) + 16)^ do
  begin
    ChangeByteOrder(sSerialNumber, sizeof(sSerialNumber));
    SetString(Result, sSerialNumber, sizeof(sSerialNumber));
  end;
end;

function GetDeviceHandle(sDeviceName: String): THandle;
begin
  Result := CreateFile(PChar('\\.\' + sDeviceName), GENERIC_READ or
    GENERIC_WRITE, FILE_SHARE_READ or FILE_SHARE_WRITE, nil,
    OPEN_EXISTING, 0, 0);
end;

function ScsiHddSerialNumber(DeviceHandle: THandle): String;
{$ALIGN ON}
type
  TScsiPassThrough = record
    Length: Word;
    ScsiStatus: Byte;
    PathId: Byte;
    TargetId: Byte;
    Lun: Byte;
    CdbLength: Byte;
    SenseInfoLength: Byte;
    DataIn: Byte;
    DataTransferLength: ULONG;
    TimeOutValue: ULONG;
    DataBufferOffset: DWORD;
    SenseInfoOffset: ULONG;
    Cdb: Array [0 .. 15] of Byte;
  end;

  TScsiPassThroughWithBuffers = record
    spt: TScsiPassThrough;
    bSenseBuf: Array [0 .. 31] of Byte;
    bDataBuf: Array [0 .. 191] of Byte;
  end;
  { ALIGN OFF }
var
  dwReturned: DWORD;
  len: DWORD;
  Buffer: Array [0 .. sizeof(TScsiPassThroughWithBuffers) +
    sizeof(TScsiPassThrough) - 1] of Byte;
  sptwb: TScsiPassThroughWithBuffers absolute Buffer;
begin
  Result := '';
  FillChar(Buffer, sizeof(Buffer), #0);
  with sptwb.spt do
  begin
    Length := sizeof(TScsiPassThrough);
    CdbLength := 6; // CDB6GENERIC_LENGTH
    SenseInfoLength := 24;
    DataIn := 1; // SCSI_IOCTL_DATA_IN
    DataTransferLength := 192;
    TimeOutValue := 2;
    DataBufferOffset := PChar(@sptwb.bDataBuf) - PChar(@sptwb);
    SenseInfoOffset := PChar(@sptwb.bSenseBuf) - PChar(@sptwb);
    Cdb[0] := $12; // OperationCode := SCSIOP_INQUIRY;
    Cdb[1] := $01; // Flags := CDB_INQUIRY_EVPD; Vital product data
    Cdb[2] := $80; // PageCode Unit serial number
    Cdb[4] := 192; // AllocationLength
  end;
  len := sptwb.spt.DataBufferOffset + sptwb.spt.DataTransferLength;
  if DeviceIoControl(DeviceHandle, $0004D004, @sptwb, sizeof(TScsiPassThrough),
    @sptwb, len, dwReturned, nil) and ((PChar(@sptwb.bDataBuf) + 1)^ = #$80)
  then
    SetString(Result, PChar(@sptwb.bDataBuf) + 4,
      Ord((PChar(@sptwb.bDataBuf) + 3)^));
end;

function GetHddSerial: String;
var
  NumTry: Byte;

  FinalStr: String;
  hDevice: THandle;
  sDeviceName: String;
begin
  NumTry := 1;
  Repeat
    Case NumTry Of
      1:
        Begin
          FinalStr := Trim(GetIdeDiskSerialNumber);
        End;
      2:
        Begin
          sDeviceName := 'C:';
          hDevice := GetDeviceHandle(sDeviceName);
          If hDevice <> INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE Then
          Begin
            Try
              FinalStr := Trim(ScsiHddSerialNumber(hDevice));
            Finally
              CloseHandle(hDevice);
            End;
          End;
        End;
      3:
        Begin
          FinalStr := 'Error!';
        End;
    End;

    Inc(NumTry);
  Until (FinalStr <> '') Or (NumTry > 3);

  Result := FinalStr;
end;

end.
```

Comment: What's the question? Change all `Char` types to `AnsiChar`, change all `String` types to `AnsiString`, `PChar` to `PAnsiChar`, and Unicode isn't an issue.

Comment: Did u tried once as u said? I think that you talk so easily. Already I tried like as you said, But still there are problems... Understand?

Comment: You said no mention of trying anything. If you already attempted, and it didn't work, you need to show us exactly what you attempted, and what the result was which didn't work. Understand? Stack Overflow isn't a code writing or conversion service. @KenWhite was merely responding to your question with the solution based on what we can see. You already know it's a unicode issue, and there are plenty of docs out there explaining how to go about this shift.

Comment: If you *tried it already*, why does your code not show that effort? **Try what I said**. If it doesn't work, **post the code that shows that attempt**, explain **exactly** how it's not working as expected, and we can try to help. Saying "Here's code. I tried something else but it didn't work. There are problems.* is absolutely useless and wastes both your time and ours.

Comment: @KenWhite There's not even a mention of trying at all until after your comment...

Comment: Currently not errors anyone, But when runs, Result didn't show HDD Serial no, but showed 'Error !'. Of course I have been to change already all char to Ansichar, and String to AnsiString, Pchar to PAnsiChar. But result not changed at all...

Comment: Why are you using `Buffer` and typecasting it to `PSendCmdInParams`? Declare a variable of type `TSendCmdInParams`, populate it's fields, and then use that variable with an `@` before it. `Buffer` is not a `PSendCmdInParams` - it's an array of bytes - and typecasting it to one doesn't magically convert it. The code you've posted is a horrific mess, and I don't think it worked in any version of Delphi, and I don't think the problems are related to the change to Unicode.

Answer (score 2):

Beside the required Pchar -> PAnsiChar fix, one problem that is easy to miss is

```
  System.Move('SCSIDISK', srbControl.Signature, 8);
```

The string is passed in as a PChar to the `move` function. To fix it, I changed it to a typed const

```
const
  kScsiDisk : AnsiString = 'SCSIDISK';
[...]
  System.Move(kScsiDisk , srbControl.Signature, 8);
```

After fixing that, converting PChar -> PAnsiChar and Char -> AnsiChar, the code started returning a valid value on my system.

There also seems to be an issue with the `GetDeviceHandle`. You are using '\.\C:' to open the device, but from what I can tell, you should be using '\.\PhysicalDriveX' (Where X is the sequence of your drive). Then again, I'm not very familiar with querying device in this fashion so I might be missing something.

Comment: I think he also can use TEncoding class functions :-)
Though good oldschool Move is so cule :-D

Comment: I personally would avoid strings. It's just an array of 8 bytes. Declare it as a const and assign it. To me that is so much cleaner than messing with text encodings.